# Whatsapp restore error on new phone, stucks at %24

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I got error while transfering whatapp from old phone to new phone.

My old phone is mi5s plus xiaomi

New phone is red mi note 9 pro xiaomi.

I uploaded to drive and put to local. So, I have backup both place, drive and local. Then I put local file backup to pc and get from pc to red mi note 9 pro. And put to whatsapp/databases folder

I tried everything here:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/whatsapp-restore-stuck-24-restoration-t3816605/page3

I enter my number, I got verification code. THen it asks to restore from drive or skip. I tried both. I have problem at %31 while restoring from drive.

If i disable and click skip for drive restoration, it finds local but this time it stucks at %24 and then it goes to application settings, profile photo. But i immediately force stop and open again but again comes as I would start application so i clear data and it again asks verification code . But i have to wait hours when i want a code. Now, I have to wait 12 hours for example. It increases for every try.

There is only crypt file. Please help me to fix.

Size is 1.25 gb but whatsapp show 3.9 gb to restore. in whatsapp folder, there is 3.9 gb data.
I tried lots of things but it keeps failing.

For old phone, I still could not enable internet so whatsapp is still there logged. I can do backups, it makes again 1.25 gb. I think if i enable wifi, it will logout.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed. I tried for days. Every time I requested a new verification code, the time I had to wait increased every time. Last time, it was 49 hours. Luckily, I fixed and did not wait so much.

I tried lots of time but i will tell what i did for latest try.

Firstly, I deleted drive backup. I did not disable sycn or google accounts.

I had 2 local backups. Deleted one.

And maybe those are important: I gave all permissions from settings to whatsapp. I gave also autostart permission and I gave no battery restriction.

Sim card is on different phone. This is not important i think.

I started to restore. It restored local backup. When it came to %24, i was worried. So, I switched to screens once a second, to settings screen.

Normally it was showing 3.9 gb at first. But when it reached %24, it was 3.18 gb when I was switching to settings screen, i saw it. And 2.5 millions messages are restored and it is 3.18 gb.

I waited it to be 3.9 gb when it was at %24. So that is why i was switching to check but it did not stuck this time. Maybe because i was switching.

Maybe because i removed from drive. This was the first time i tried after removing from drive.

So, switching a lot of times between settings of whatsapp and restoring screen, showed succesfull screen at last. IT said "restored 2.5 millions messaged"

I was shocked. I went to check. 5 days ago, i wrote last message and that 5 days messages also came.

If it was stuck again, i would force stop and continue without waiting restore. I read it from somewhere. But i fixed, i am happy :)

Comment: I assume you lost all your images and the like. Can they copied back to the WA directory in order to be able to view them again in the chats? (I´ve backed up everything on a hard drive before switching phones)  
I´m also waiting the 49 hours